# Display permission before activity is loaded

Tags: android, google-maps, android-permissions, setcontentview

I have noticed a few posters on Stack Overflow attempting this, but my situation is a little different. I have a Login class and when the user authenticates, I take declare an Intent to them to my NavDrawer class, which serves as the Main Activity. I am using a Map Fragment to show a Google Map, but when the user logs in for the very first time, the blue dot ( call to setMyLocationEnabled = true) is not visible. This is due to the Map loading in the background before the location permission request is loaded. Of course, after you grant permission and restart the app manually, the blue dot is visible as permission is already granted.

I am trying to build my logic so that as soon as the user logs in, they must grant permission before the map will load. That way, the blue dot will be enabled.

Apparently this is a known bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73122459

And one suggestion in the link above is to request permission in Activity before calling setContentView. I attempted to do this, but my Map is still loading in the background. Since location is integral to the app, I was thinking I could throw up a screen that prevents the map from being shown, that takes them to their settings. Then when they return, the map will be visible.

I like how LimeBike does it, with a transparent map behind it, so you still see what should be there. Once you navigate to your settings and enable location and return, their map loads and the blue dot pops up. Does anyone have experience implementing something similar?

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

If showing blue dot is so essencial on first launch before permissions granted - why not trying to request permission on preivious screen. Right on Login screen. And to not disturb users too early - do it after user successfully logins.

i.e.
1. User logs in
2. User stays on Login screen, sees popup with permission
3. Accepts or declines - either way navigates to Map screen

Answer (score 0):

put that permissionns code into the onstart , only after permission success call on createview.

Answer (score 0):

If your app flow allows you to request the location permission *before* showing the `MapView`, that's the simplest solution. You might also potentially be able to use a static map image in the background on your first launch, and then switch over to the screen with the real map after the permission request, depending on what you need to show there.

Alternatively, if you want or have to have the `MapView` visible behind the permission-request dialog, I've found that you can take one of two approaches to restart the `MapView`, whereupon it will properly get location updates in the "My Location" layer (the blue dot). You do this from `onRequestPermissionsResult`, if permission has been granted.

### 1. Replace the MapView

I placed the `MapView`, by itself, in a `FrameLayout`. First save the state of the existing `MapView` and shut it down:

```
val oldMapState = Bundle()
with(mapView) {
    onSaveInstanceState(oldMapState)
    onPause()
    onStop()
    onDestroy()
}
```

Then create a new `MapView`, run it up through to "resumed" state, and swap it in to the FrameLayout, in place of the old map view:

```
val mapContainer = branchMapView.parent as FrameLayout
val newBranchMapView = MapView(mapContainer.context).apply {
    onCreate(oldMapState)
    getMapAsync { it.isMyLocationEnabled = true }
    onStart()
    onResume()
}
```

There will be a flash of background while the new `MapView` loads, but I haven't found it too bothersome. One could probably refine this further to hide the new `MapView` for a couple of seconds, while it loads, but I don't know of a way to monitor the loading progress, so it would never be perfect; and you would run the risk of the interrupting the user manipulating the old map before you cut over.

### 2. Restart the MapView

The second approach is similar, but instead of creating a new `MapView`, we just restart the same one. As far as I can tell, calling `onCreate` again, after `onDestroy` seems to have no ill effects, **except** that the background goes solid black for a moment, for some reason, which I find doesn't look as good. It also wouldn't allow you to do any overlapped loading of the new map, if you wanted to try to minimize the visual disruption. However, from a code perspective, it seems like a slightly simpler solution.

---

If you are using a `MapFragment`, perhaps you can do something similar, removing the old fragment and adding a new one dynamically. (Not sure if re-use is possible; I have only tested with a `MapView`.)